# How can I hide the upper left health bar?

Tags: commandos-2

I'm desperate to know how to hide this health bar, it just appears from nowhere, and I tried all keys possible but it still remains:

[image]

How can I hide the upper left health bar?

Comment: I'm not entirely certain it is even possible to remove these. I'm at work now, so can't check it.

Comment: @Arperum got it, simply click the character face at the bottom right, the health bar will disappear, lol !!!!

Comment: Then post that solution as an answer too, self answering is a good thing! (And accept it in two days, because you won't be able to accept it faster I think)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply click the character face at the bottom right, the health bar will disappear!